# My Flexbox has weird not necessary padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, frontend, padding

I am working on a simple tool that display stats.
We want to display 2 panels, of the same height width small boxed inside, all of the same height.

My result is very close to what we want to produce, but the boxes has weird padding.

```
<div class="col-md-6 greybox">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Title of the box</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 flex">
    <div class="row flex">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="statbox">
          <div class="absolute-center">
            <h3>Revelant</h3>
            <p>lorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="statbox">
          <div class="absolute-center">
            <h3>Revelant data</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The full script is availlable at http://codepen.io/joe_desmeules/pen/LRBKEp
- We are using Bootstrap 3.7.
- We are using Scss.
- Im not interested using Jquery to fix the issue (we use Angular2)
- The data will be dynamic. I can't use fixed height to fix the issue.
- The provided codepen is a prototype, with placeholder color, i promise the result will have prettier colors :).
- The weird padding is probably caused by the title of the box, but i dont know how to fix it.
- Removing the title, and edit the CSS of the `.greybox` fix the issue
- We need to keep the title in the final result.

Thank you for helping me, im out of ideas!

(Sorry, english isn't my first language)

Comment: codePen page not found!

Comment: How would they look like?Any sketch or picture or codepen?

Comment: full script link is broken

Comment: http://codepen.io/joe_desmeules/pen/LRBKEp

Comment: Im sorry, it seem the code pen was broken.
I just put a new link

Comment: https://s17.postimg.org/k3l9pjsr3/padding.png

There is an useless padding on top and bottom of the white box, that is the same size of the title.

Answer (score 0):

I have update your css(scss), it dont have any padding or white space which u were pointing in ur image, see codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLOBwQ)

```
h2{
      margin: 0;
    }

html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  .greybox {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .statbox {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    bottom: 0px;
    h3 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #1155cc;
      margin: 0;
    }

  }
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    //flex-direction: row;
    //justify-content: space-around;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .absolute-center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/3mp8r55d7/Sans_titre_1.jpg

There is still a padding under the text (in green).

I dont know where it's comming from.